# Simple router in ReactJS without ReactRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router

I've read that ReactRouter sucks.

How can I render different components strictly based on particular routes, i.e, with:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Game />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

How could I change this to use something like this that I found [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/you-might-not-need-react-router-38673620f3d):

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/', action: () => <HomePage /> },
  { path: '/game', action: () => <Game /> },
  { path: '/game2', action: () => <Game2 /> }
];
```

I feel like this should NOT be that complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I have done for a simple app I have:

```
class SimpleRouter extends React.Component {
  render() {
    {this.getContainer()}
  }

  getContainer() {
    const url = window.location.href;

    const routes = [
      { path: '/', action: () => <HomePage /> },
      { path: '/game', action: () => <Game /> },
      { path: '/game2', action: () => <Game2 /> }
    ];

    const route = routes.find(r => url.endsWith(r));

    if (route && route.action) {
      return route.action();
    } else {
      return <DefaultContainer />;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for subpaths like `a/b` (not found). Is there a workaround as long as I don't want to use React Router?